# how to write or change a value in json file with angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have this json file. Can I write into this file or change a value without node js just angular? I want to change watch to true is it possible?

```
   [
    {
        "id":1,
        "label": "The Crown",
        "image": "crown.jpg",
        "genre": "Drama",
        "rate": 3,
        "watch": false
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "label": "Venom",
        "image": "venom.jpg",
        "genre": "Marvel",
        "rate": 1,
        "watch": false
    },
]
```

Comment: Do you need to transform the data, or *write* something into the _physical_ file?

Comment: @PhilippMeissner yup

Comment: That will be be possible with Angular only.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have

```
items = [
  {
    "id":1,
    "label": "The Crown",
    "image": "crown.jpg",
    "genre": "Drama",
    "rate": 3,
    "watch": false
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "label": "Venom",
    "image": "venom.jpg",
    "genre": "Marvel",
    "rate": 1,
    "watch": false
  },
]
```

In javascript / typescript, you can do

```
items[0].watch = true;
```